# Test SQL Server connection for an Active Directory account

Tags: sql-server, connection, database-connection

I have a SQL Server login created (Windows Authentication) and SQL Server user linked to the login.

I want to test the connection to this SQL Server from another server on the network for this particular Active Directory account (different than my AD account). I do not have a SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio) installed on the server I want to test the connection from.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you how do you test that? Try to connect to the SQL Server from the other server, just like you would when. Your on the localhost.

Comment: Thanks Larnu. I updated the question. I do not have a SQL Server Management Studio installed on the machine I need to test the connection from.

Comment: Have you considered installing it? If not, how about sqlcmd? YOu need a tool to test the connection; you can't test a connection if you have no tools you can use to connect.

Comment: I am not able to install any software on this server due to permissions.

Comment: Then you can't test... If you have no software on the machine that *can* connect to SQL Server, and you won't be installing any software that can, then why do you need to test if it can? You have no need to test it, however, coincidently your test is complete; it can't connect to SQL Server, as it has no means of doing so.

Comment: I've voted to close this, as the it seems that the problem the OP has cannot be reproduced; on the basis they want to test connecting to SQL Server on a Server that has no means of doing so.

Comment: This is actually a useful question - and the answer using a udl file is a helpful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is how I tested it:

1. Create a Microsoft Data Link file (.udl) anywhere on the client machine. Just create a new test.txt file and rename it to **test.udl**
2. Opening the properties dialogue of .udl file lets you test the connection to a SQL Server. My problem was that the connection to the SQL Server needs to be tested for an AD account different than mine. To do this, run the command prompt as that user on the client machine:

   [image]
3. In command prompt, navigate to the folder that contains test.udl file and type the name of the file in the prompt.
4. This will open the properties of the .udl file. Go to Connection tab and provide the SQL server name:

   [image]
5. Select "Use Windows NT Integrated security" in section #2:

   [image]
6. When you click on the database drop-down in section #3 and you are able to see the list of databases, that means that the login worked for the user. If you wish you can select a database from the list and click "Test Connection" button to test a specific database connection.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it helped me! I think this is the best option when there is no other tool in the environment available.

Comment: Glad it helped Ethan.